# Are there any compatibility issues in browsers when using identical CSS class identifiers for different elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if it is okay to use identical class names for parts in different "parent" (regarding CSS class) elements.

For example:

```css
.section, .panel {
  background: black;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
}

/* First .head */
.section .head{
  background: yellow;
}

/* Second .head */
.panel .head{
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="head">
    Section Head
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel">
  <div class="head">
    Panel Head
  </div>
</div>
```

Both, section and panel, have a header which has different styling but the same identifier ".head". I only define rules for ".head" when it is inside of the element ".section" or ".panel", but never for a plain ".head". So, now I'm wondering if this can cause any compatibility issues or is this perfectly acceptable across most browsers? (including IE8+)

Comment: I think it is just okay, at long as you specify it and not create a general style for `.head`

Comment: This is perfectly acceptable in any browser that understands the most basic HTML and CSS. That alone will not cause you an issue anywhere.

Comment: just bear in mind that usually classes are meant to be used for elements that are similarly styled so you may get into trouble down the road if someone who doesn't code very well comes a long and tries to alter the code by doing `.head { color:blue !important }` not realising they are changing 2 types of head.  I would tend to go with a `.panel-head` and `.section-head` (if the styles of the .head were different,  f you want them to be the same styling header, then I would use the same class) - that way it also keeps the length of the selector down too

Comment: I would say this is how you should use CSS that's why it will work on any browser supporting CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you keep track of the classes, it should be ok. Its more readability than compatibility, so be carefull and dont overuse it.

Futhermore, when you are adding more styles also be carefull if styling one new feature, affects past ones due to repeated classes.

Comment: Even if you don't keep track of the classes it will be ok. I think you should be more clear that this is absolutely fine. There are no caveats -- this is perfectly valid CSS/HTML.

Comment: @GregSchmit sure, its perfecly valid as you say, but scalability does not, i'm just making this appointment ;)